# Route name for a group doesn't apply

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

So I ran into a problem, where I wanted my routes to look nice and tidy, found an example, but the name 'admin.' isn't registered in front of the route names in the routes list.

```
Route::group([
    'namespace' => 'Admin',
    'middleware' => 'admin',
    'prefix' => 'admin',
    'name' => 'admin.'
    ], function () {
        Route::resource('articles', 'ArticleController');
});
```

If I make it a bit different, then everything is okay.

```
Route::group([
    'namespace' => 'Admin',
    'middleware' => 'admin',
    'prefix' => 'admin',
    ], function () {
        Route::name('admin.')->group(function () {
            Route::resource('articles', 'ArticleController');
        });
});
```

Can someone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for the key `'as'` instead of `'name'` in this instance:

```
Route::group([
    'namespace' => 'Admin',
    'middleware' => 'admin',
    'prefix' => 'admin',
    'as' => 'admin.'
    ], function () {
        Route::resource('articles', 'ArticleController');
});
```

When it comes to setting those attributes up via method calls `name` can be used which is just an alias for `as`. Ex:

```
Route::name('admin.')->group(...);
```

Even for Route objects, `name` is just setting an attribute named `as`:

```
Route::get(..., ...)->name('blah'); // is actually setting `as`
```